# How to create a drop down list with pages to a themes options page?

Tags: options, api, dropdown

I'm building a themes options page using settings API. Everything is ok, but i now i want to create a drop down list populated with pages and i don't know how to!

For example, i have this piece of code that show the list of pages, but when i select a page and cick on save, the page selected doesn't get saved!

```
    function  combo_select_page_callback() {
$options = get_option('journal_theme_blog_2_col');
    echo "<select name='select_page'>
 <option value=''>";
echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?></option>
 <?php
  $pages = get_pages();
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $selected = '<option value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
    $selected .= $page->post_title;
    $selected .= '</option>';
    echo $selected;
  }
echo '</select>';
}// end combo_select_page_callback
```

Thank for the help,
nelson

Comment: Add the code you use to save the data.

Comment: I think i have found the solution:

Comment: @naires Then add it as answer, wait for two days and mark it as solution.

Comment: You are right kaiser. i just did. thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I used the wordpress function [wp_dropdown_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages)

```
<?php function  combo_select_page_callback() {
$options = get_option('function plugin');
    wp_dropdown_pages(
        array(
             'name' => 'function plugin[ID used to identify the field throughout the theme]',
             'echo' => 1,
             'show_option_none' => __( '&mdash; Select &mdash;' ),
             'option_none_value' => '0',
             'selected' => $options['ID used to identify the field throughout the theme']
        )
    );
} ?>
```